# speed select vs join

Tags: mysql, select, join

The two quires below do the same thing. Basically show all the id's of table 1, which are present in table 2.  The thing which puzzles me is that the **simple select** is *way way* faster than the **JOIN**, I would have expected that the JOIN is a bit slower, but not by that much...5 seconds vs. 0.2

Can anyone elaborate on this ?

```
SELECT table1.id FROM       
table1,table2 WHERE 
table1.id=table2.id
```

***Duration/Fetch 0.295/0.028*** (MySql Workbench 5.2.47)

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.id
```

***Duration/Fetch 5.035/0.027*** (MySql Workbench 5.2.47)

Comment: The first one uses a join as well (just the outdated syntax with implicit joins in the where clause). As both are 100% equal in terms of what they should do, I would suspect a bug in MySQL here.

Comment: Which one did you run first? What does EXPLAIN say?

Comment: They're the same query. I suspect the you're looking at the cache

Comment: As Strawberry points out, the difference you observed is likely due to the query cache (subsequent execution of the exact same SQL text will have results returned from a cache, rather than being executed by the database. (For testing, use the `NO_SQL_CACHE` hint to bypass the query cache.) That's the same query, just a slight difference in syntax. Before we race down "a bug in MySQL" path with @horse_with_no_name, be sure you are comparing apples to apples. Because there shouldn't be any difference between those apples, because they are the **same apple**.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Can anyone elaborate on this?

**A:** Before we go the "a bug in MySQL" route that @a_horse_with_no_name seems impatient to race down, we'd really need to ensure that this is repeatable behavior, and isn't just a quirk.

And to do that, we'd really need to see the elapsed time result from more than one run of the query.

If the query cache is enabled on the server, we want to run the queries with the `SQL_NO_CACHE` hint added (`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE table1.id ...`) so we know we aren't retrieving cached results.

I'd repeat the execution of each query at least three times, and throw out the result from the first run, and average the other runs. (The purpose of this is to eliminate the impact of the table data not being in the cache, either InnoDB buffer, or the filesystem cache.)

Also, run an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each query. And compare the access plans.

If either of these tables is MyISAM storage engine, note that MyISAM tables are subject to locking by DML operations; while an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operation is run on the table, the SELECT statements will be blocked from accessing the table. (But five seconds seems a bit much for that, unless these are really large tables, or really inefficient DML statements).

With InnoDB, the SELECT queries won't be blocked by DML operations.

Elapsed time is also going to depend on what else is going on on the system.

But the total elapsed time is going include more than just the time in the MySQL server. Temporarily turning on the MySQL general_log would allow you to capture the statements that are actually being processed by the server.

Comment: thank you very much for replying, I will switch off the cache and try both queries again. And yes, both tables are really large, the result set was a little more than 17000

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that could be further optimized by the database engine if indeed you are running both queries under the exact same context.

SQL is declarative.  By successfully declaring what you want, the engine has free reign to restructure the "How" of your request to bring back the fastest result.

The earliest versions of SQL didn't even have the keyword JOIN.  There was only the comma.

There are many coding constructs in SQL that imperatively force a single inferior methodology over another and they should be avoided.  JOIN shouldn't be avoided.  Something sounds a miss.  JOIN is the core element of SQL.  It would be a shame to always have to use commas.

There are a zillion factors that go into the performance of a JOIN all based your environment, schema, and data.  Chances are that your table1 and table2 represent a fringe case that may have gotten past the optimization algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL_NO_CACHE worked, the new results are:

Duration/Fetch 5.065 / 0.027 for the select where  and
Duration/Fetch 5.050 / 0.027 for the join

I would have thought that the "select where" would be faster, but the join was actually a tad swifter. But the difference is negligible

I would like to thank everyone for their response.